# Ajax result show in console if is called outside function and not showing in array

Tags: php, ajax, jquery

In wordpress theme I must change custom functionality and use ajax, so I have dropdown and on change I grab selected option:

JS

```
$( ".select-class" ).change(function(e) {

    var postofficeval = $(this).val();
    $.ajax({
        method: "POST",
        url: ajaxurl,
        //url: "urltophpfile.php", 
        //action: "postnum_ajax",
        data: {"post_office": postofficeval }
        //data: {ajaxselectedcode: $(this).val()}
      })
        .done(function( msg ) {
          console.log( "Data Saved: " + msg );
        });
});
```

In console I see:

Data Saved: Array
(
[post_office] => 3330
)

if I print this in php I get empty array:

```
print_r($_POST) 
and If I try with var:
$postalnum = $_POST['post_office']
```

which I need to manipulate showing data in future also not working.

Also if I uncomment action and add

print_r($_POST)  in:

```
function postnum_ajax() {

    // if ( isset($_POST) ) {
    //  $postalnum = $_POST['post_office'];

    // }

    print_r($_POST);
   

   die();
}

add_action( 'wp_ajax_postnum_ajax', 'postnum_ajax' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_postnum_ajax', 'postnum_ajax' );
```

Also if I declare and echo outside of function:

```
$postalNum = $_POST['post_office']; 
echo $postalNum;
```

is see value of echo in console after request value but not on display.

Can anyone help me please? I need this selected post_num to manipulate in php which content is showing.

Thanks for help,

Comment: You haven’t defined `action` in your AJAX request. You’ve commented it out, but it needs to be inside `data`.

Comment: thanks for direction